# Can I programmatically add an aspx control inside a dynamically created html span?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I create controls all the time in code behind and I also use a html span from time to time but can I use both together?

If I load an aspx page with:

```html
<div id="test" runat="server"></div>
```

Then I create a control in my normal way as bellow

```vb
Sub add_btn(ByVal CssClass As String, ByVal btn_ID As String, ByVal find_control As String, ByVal text As String)
    Dim Btn As New Button()
    Btn.ID = btn_ID
    Btn.Text = text
    Btn.CssClass = CssClass
    Btn.UseSubmitBehavior = False
    AddHandler Btn.Click, AddressOf btn_Click

    pnl_stage.FindControl(find_control).Controls.Add(Btn)
End Sub
```

This works great!

But what I need to do is create the div at run time using a span as bellow
ASPX

```html
<span id="span_edit" runat="server"></span>
```

CODE BEHIND

```vb
span_edit.InnerHtml = "<div id=""test"" runat=""server""></div>"
```

If I now try and use my sub to add a button it errors with object not found.
I can only think doing it this way the div has not been created before I try and create the control.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Where are you setting the innerHTML for the span? which event? The way viewstate works, the innerHTML/div might not have existed during the click event.

Comment: Page_load is where I set the inner html but it doesn't manage to create the aspx btn and I get object not found error.